# ASP NET Identity Manager database permissions

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-identity, identity-management

I have got Identity Manager set up and running locally, working with ASP.NET Identity. I have a SQL Server 2012 database for the backend. I can create a user and get a list back, however whenever I try and create a role, edit a user or list the roles i get the following:

CREATE DATABASE permission denied in database 'master'.

The user i have in the connection string is a valid SQL login and is a user on the database that Identity Manager is pointed at, (and obviously can login as i can see the user in the database table) however it seems like for these actions the database is claiming the user connecting hasn't got permission.

I am running the app pool for identity manager under the AppPoolIdentity.

Appreciate any help.

Comment: I wasn't passing in the context to my role store, once i did this and passed my role in to the role store and role manager (not the base class like i was doing), i then got

An error occurred when trying to create a controller of type 'MetaController'. Make sure that the controller has a parameterless public constructor.

Comment: I found this issue because I also got this error: `An error occurred when trying to create a controller of type 'MetaController'. Make sure that the controller has a parameterless public constructor.` I created ['another issue'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33354145/asp-net-identity-manager-error-error-when-trying-to-create-a-controller-of-type/33354290#33354290) for it, which also details the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So issues were due to first of all me not passing my context to the role store (i was passing it to my user store however) and then making sure the identity manager service was getting my role manager. After i went through all the dependencies carefully i got it all working with no issues.