# ASP.NET Identity Manager Error: error when trying to create a controller of type 'MetaController' (no parameterless public constructor)

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-identity, thinktecture-ident-server

I got ThinkTecture's IdentityManager running, but now when going to the '/idm/ url I get an error:

```
An error occurred when trying to create a controller of type 'MetaController'. Make sure that the controller has a parameterless public constructor.
```

The error was mentioned in a comment in [another StackOverflow issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30400093/asp-net-identity-manager-database-permissions) but a solution to this issue was not given.
[image]

Answer (score 7):

While formulating this question I also found the solution in [`an issue of the IdentityManager GitHub repo`](https://github.com/IdentityManager/IdentityManager/issues/121). I had to change the constructor for `ApplicationUserManager` in `IdentityConfig.cs` from:

```
public ApplicationUserManager(IUserStore<ApplicationUser> store): base(store) {}
```

to:

```
public ApplicationUserManager(ApplicationUserStore store): base(store) {}
```

And a similar type change in the `Create` function just below that to get everything compiling.

The `ApplicationUserStore` should be defined as follows.

```
public class ApplicationUserStore: UserStore<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationUserStore(ApplicationDbContext ctx): base(ctx) {}
}
```

I put it in `Startup.cs` just above the declaration of `ApplicationRoleStore`.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, but instead of modifying constructors, I fixed it by tweaking the DI registration

```
    public static void ConfigureMyCustomIdentityManagerService(this IdentityManagerServiceFactory factory, string connectionString)
    {
        factory.Register(new Registration<UserManager<User, Guid>>(x => new MyCustomUserManager(new MsSqlUserStore<User>(connectionString))));
        factory.Register(new Registration<RoleManager<Role, Guid>>(x => new RoleManager<Role, Guid>(new MsSqlRoleStore<Role>(connectionString))));

        factory.IdentityManagerService = new Registration<IIdentityManagerService, AspNetIdentityManagerService<User, Guid, Role, Guid>>();
    }
```